# Tengo un archivo JSON, pero quiero imprimir o acceder solamente a `owner_id` o `prices`

Tags: python, json

Este es el archivo:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Cargador",
    "code": "12",
    "description": "rerer",
    "unit": "12",
    "visible_to": "3",
    "owner_id": {
        "id": 11321795,
        "name": "SAUL BALDERRAMA PEREZ",
        "email": "1630275@upv.edu.mx",
        "value": 11321795
    },
    "add_time": "2020-01-13 19:18:31",
    "update_time": "2020-01-17 22:52:45",
    "prices": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "price": 1000,
            "currency": "MXN",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Caja",
    "code": "123",
    "owner_id": {
        "id": 11321795,
        "name": "SAUL BALDERRAMA PEREZ",
        "email": "1630275@upv.edu.mx",
        "value": 11321795
    },
    "add_time": "2020-01-13 20:52:46",
    "update_time": "2020-01-13 20:52:46",
    "prices": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "product_id": 2,
            "price": 100,
            "currency": "MXN",
        }
    ]
},
```

Al que solo quiero acceder a los datos del `price` o `owner_id`, pero de todos los que se encuentran en el archivo.

Por ejemplo:

```
"prices": [
{
  "id": 2,
  "product_id": 2,
  "price": 100,
  "currency": "MXN",
  "cost": 0,
  "overhead_cost": null
}]

"prices": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "product_id": 1,
    "price": 1000,
    "currency": "MXN",
    "cost": 0,
    "overhead_cost": null
  }]
```

Comment: Bienvenido SAUL BALDERRAMA PEREZ a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Como sugerencia adicional, agrega algún comentario o código de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora, ya que tu pregunta, planteada de esta forma, parece del tipo "Hagan mi tarea/trabajo", que no suele ser algo bien recibido por la comunidad. Saludos

Comment: y que intentaste?

Comment: Una disculpa, es la primera ves que publico una pregunta en esta plataforma, Bueno lo que he intenta es recorrer el json mediante un bucle for y pasarlo a  otro archivo json pero me marca error no encuentra el indice

Comment: El problema es que el código que compartiste no es el de un JSON válido, al menos que pueda ser importable por el módulo `json` de python. ¿De dónde se genera?

Answer (score 1):

## Error de sintaxis en el archivo `JSON`

Esto normalmente se presenta cuando un objeto no se encuentra correctamente definido, como es el caso del  archivo `.json` que tienes con este tipo de sintaxis:

```
{
  "clave": "valor"
},

{
  "clave": "valor"
}
```

Entonces, para que el caso anterior funcione deberás realizar una pequeña modificación colocando todo su contenido entre corchetes (`[]`):

```
[
  {
    "clave": "valor"
  },

  {
    "clave": "valor"
  } 
]
```

Teniendo claro lo expuesto anteriormente, tu código quedaría así:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Cargador",
    "code": "12",
    "description": "rerer",
    "unit": "12",
    "visible_to": "3",

    "owner_id": {
        "id": 11321795,
        "name": "SAUL BALDERRAMA PEREZ",
        "email": "1630275@upv.edu.mx",
        "value": 11321795
    },

    "add_time": "2020-01-13 19:18:31",
    "update_time": "2020-01-17 22:52:45",

    "prices": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "price": 1000,
            "currency": "MXN"
        }
    ]
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Caja",
    "code": "123",

    "owner_id": {
      "id": 11321795,
      "name": "SAUL BALDERRAMA PEREZ",
      "email": "1630275@upv.edu.mx",
      "value": 11321795
    },

    "add_time": "2020-01-13 20:52:46",
    "update_time": "2020-01-13 20:52:46",

    "prices": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "product_id": 2,
        "price": 100,
        "currency": "MXN"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Nota:** esta respuesta no se puede tomar como definitiva, considerándose que existen mejores soluciones para ello. El objetivo es brindar orientación sobre tema.

También puedes ampliarlo consultando la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) o revisando la documentación de Mozilla, titulado [Trabajando con JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres acceder mediante un bucle a un diccionario nesteado (diccionarios dentro de diccionarios), puedes usar `items()`, que convierte el primer diccionario a tuplas y cada tupla tiene dos elementos: la clave y el valor.

## 1. Bucle for normal

```
#Importamos el archivo json
import json
with open('Edreams_scraping/October/tripadvisor_data_october.json') as f:
    diccionario = json.load(f)

#Extraemos la info de prices
#k la clave, v el valor,cojemos el valor de la primera clave que es un diccionario y obtenemos el precio

precio_articulos = []

for k, v in diccionario.items():
   precio_articulos .append(v['prices'])
```

## 2. List comprehension

```
#Leemos json
import json
with open('Edreams_scraping/October/tripadvisor_data_october.json') as f:
    diccionario = json.load(f)

#Extraemos prices
precio_articulos = [v['prices'] for k, v in diccionario.items()]
```

Comment: Hola Alberto, acabo de revertir tu edición a la pregunta, editaste el código dejando la idea que la estructura es un diccionario ya conformado, cuando el autor habla específicamente de: "tengo ese archivo json" que no es lo mismo, si eventualmente el archivo fuera válido, a tu respuesta solo le faltaría indicar como cargar el mismo en un diccionario. PD:  Hay un consenso bastante extendido en la comunidad de SOes, de editar lo menos posible el código original para evitar estos problemas. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, disculpa no entendí bien la pregunta. Gracias por darte cuenta y la recomendación :) .

Answer (score 0):

Si te sirve más simple:

```
a = *tu JSON* (acordate de que empieze y termine con '[' y ']', respectivamente)

for n in range(len(a)):
    a[n]['owner_id']
```

y lo mismo para "prices":

```
for n in range(len(a)):
    a[n]['prices']
```

lo que te devuelve lo podes cargar en una lista o guardar en un base de datos, lo que quieras.

Slds.-